# Laravel nested relationships from a ternary pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, relationship

I have three entity tables, `student`, `course`, and `semester`.  They are linked together by a ternary pivot table - that is, each row represents "student X taking course Y in semester Z":

```
# Table course_students

| student_id | semester_id | course_id |
|------------|-------------|-----------|
|     18     |     4       |    80     |
|     18     |     8       |    64     |
|     18     |     8       |    60     |
```

From this, I'd like to build a nested collection such that:

- Each student has a collection containing the semesters in which that student had at least one course;
- Each semester for a given student has a collection containing the courses the student took in that semester.

So, for the above table, I'd like to call something like `Student::find(18)->with('coursesBySemester')` and get a collection that looks like:

```
{
    "id": 18,
    "first_name": "Wesley",
    "last_name": "Snipes",
    "email": "wes@expendables.com",
    "semesters": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Fall 2014",
            "pivot": {
                "student_id": 18,
                "semester_id": 4
            },
            "courses": [
                {
                    "id": 80,
                    "title": "Game Theory",
                    "pivot": {
                        "semester_id": 4,
                        "course_id": 80,
                        "student_id": 18
                    }
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Fall 2016",
            "pivot": {
                "student_id": 18,
                "semester_id": 8
            },
            "courses": [
                {
                    "id": 64,
                    "title": "Introduction to Calculus with Applications",
                    "pivot": {
                        "semester_id": 8,
                        "course_id": 64,
                        "student_id": 18
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 60,
                    "title": "Introduction to Finite Math 1",
                    "pivot": {
                        "semester_id": 8,
                        "course_id": 60,
                        "student_id": 18
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

### What I've tried

I can get most of the way there with the following relationship defined in my `Student` model:

```
/**
 * Load a collection of semesters during which this student was enrolled in at least one course, and the courses that they took in each semester
 */
public function coursesBySemester()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('UserFrosting\Sprinkle\Btoms\Model\Semester', 'course_students')
    ->with(['courses' => function ($query) {
        return $query->where('course_students.student_id', $this->id);
    }])
    ->groupBy('semester_id');
}
```

The `Semester` model has the following relationship defined:

```
/**
 * Lazily load a collection of courses that were taken in this semester.
 */
public function courses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('UserFrosting\Sprinkle\Btoms\Model\Course', 'course_students')->withPivot('student_id');
}
```

The problem is that when I call `with('courses')` in my `coursesBySemester` relationship, it retrieves *all* courses that *any* student took in that semester.  I only want the courses that the *parent student* took in that semester.

As you can see I tried to constrain that relationship by using `where('course_students.student_id', $this->id)`, but `$this->id` does not actually have any value set in the context of the relationship.  I've also tried the `wherePivot` method, but again, I don't know how to dynamically set that constraint based on the `id` of the parent `Student` model.

I realize that I could just create a helper that manually goes through and builds the collection I want, but I'd really like to implement this as a single relationship so that I can use it fluently in other query builder expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by creating a **custom `Relation` class**.

```
<?php

// MyProject/Model/Relations/BelongsToManyConstrained.php

namespace MyProject\Model\Relations;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class BelongsToManyConstrained extends BelongsToMany
{
    /**
     * @var The pivot foreign key on which to constrain the result sets for this relation.
     */
    protected $constraintKey;

    /**
     * Create a new belongs to many relationship instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $parent
     * @param  string  $table
     * @param  string  $foreignKey
     * @param  string  $relatedKey
     * @param  string  $constraintKey
     * @param  string  $relationName
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Builder $query, Model $parent, $table, $foreignKey, $relatedKey, $constraintKey, $relationName = null)
    {
        $this->constraintKey = $constraintKey;
        parent::__construct($query, $parent, $table, $foreignKey, $relatedKey, $relationName);
    }

    /**
     * Match the eagerly loaded results to their parents, constraining the results by matching the values of $constraintKey
     * in the parent object to the child objects.
     *
     * @param  array   $models
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection  $results
     * @param  string  $relation
     * @return array
     */
    public function match(array $models, Collection $results, $relation)
    {
        $dictionary = $this->buildDictionary($results);

        // Once we have an array dictionary of child objects we can easily match the
        // children back to their parent using the dictionary and the keys on the
        // the parent models. Then we will return the hydrated models back out.
        foreach ($models as $model) {
            $pivotId = $model->getRelation('pivot')->{$this->constraintKey};

            if (isset($dictionary[$key = $model->getKey()])) {
                $items = $this->findMatchingPivots($dictionary[$key], $pivotId);
                $model->setRelation(
                    $relation, $this->related->newCollection($items)
                );
            }
        }

        return $models;
    }

    /**
     * Filter an array of models, only taking models whose $constraintKey value matches $pivotValue.
     *
     * @param mixed $pivotValue
     * @return array
     */
    protected function findMatchingPivots($items, $pivotValue)
    {
        $result = [];
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item->getRelation('pivot')->{$this->constraintKey} == $pivotValue) {
                $result[] = $item;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Now, in my `Semester` class, I can define this relationship:

```
/**
 * Lazily load a collection of courses that were taken in this semester by related students.
 */
public function coursesForStudent()
{
    $instance = $this->newRelatedInstance('MyProject\Model\Course');
    $foreignKey = $this->getForeignKey();
    $relatedKey = $instance->getForeignKey();

    $query = new BelongsToManyConstrained(
        $instance->newQuery(), $this, 'course_students', $foreignKey, $relatedKey, 'student_id', 'courses'
    );

    // Need to make sure we add the `student_id` pivot for BelongsToManyConstrained to match
    $query = $query->withPivot('student_id');

    return $query;
}
```

Notice that I've passed in `student_id` to my constructor for `BelongsToManyConstrained`.  This tells the relationship that it should only retrieve Courses whose pivot value for `student_id` matches the pivot value for the parent object's `student_id`.

I can then define a relation `coursesBySemester` in my `Student` model:

```
/**
 * Lazily load a collection of semesters during which this student was enrolled in a course.
 */
public function coursesBySemester()
{        
    return $this->belongsToMany('MyProject\Model\Semester', 'course_students')
        ->with('coursesForStudent');
}
```

Now I can get my desired nested result set via:

```
$student = Student::find(1)->with('coursesBySemester');
```

The only problem remaining is that since it creates as many related entities as as there are rows, there will be duplicate semesters when a semester contains more than one course.  I probably need to introduce another custom relationship to flatten out these duplicate values.